# how to save VS solution changed by devenv /Command "File.AddExistingProject"

Tags: devenv

I am trying to create batch script to automate the build. In which I need to add existing project in a solution, for which I used below::

**devenv solutionPath /Command "File.AddExistingProject" projectPath**

This command adds the existing project and opens the solution. But problem starts here, now how to save this solution(with added existing project).
I have found (***devenv solutionPath /Command "File.SaveAll"***) option but it opens the solution in another VS instance and saves it.

Please help to save the modified solution using devenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution. I have made below vbs script .

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Microsoft Visual Studio" 
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
WshShell.SendKeys "^+s"
```

And after using AddExistingProject command I have called this vbs script. It has worked for me.